# how to get the output of query to a csv file in oracle or by other means

Tags: database, output

I have written a plsql script. the script fetches data from multiple tables based on some criteria and formats the data to be in comma separated format. now the data that is fetched is huge in terms of number of lines as well as row size. i want that data in a csv file.
I have tried doing following things:

1. using spool with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE has limitation of only 20000 bytes, so my records are appearing half way in the spooled file.
2. using utl_file i am able to get it in a csv file, but the problem is my database resides on some other machine(physically) and my application resides on some other machine. so when i am firing the plsql script it is creating that file on the database machine. also utl_file requires creating directory objects on the database machine which will soon be a security concern for me.

Is there anyway that i can pipe the output of plsql script into a file which is located on my application machine(and not on my database machine).
You can also suggest solution in some other programming languages too like java etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. There is an optional argument to dbms_output.enable -- the buffer
   size.  It defaults to 20,000 and there is a maximum allowed of
   1,000,000 (Oracle 9i - 11g).
   `dbms_output.enable(1000000);`

   - [dbms_output: Oracle 9i](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_outpu2.htm#1000431)
   - [dbms_output: Oracle 10g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i999293)
   - [dbms_output: Oracle 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_output.htm#i999293)
2. If that's not enough space, then you may need to run your PL/SQL block to output only a  chunk of your desired output at a time.
3. Can you re-write your PL/SQL block as an SQL query?  Then if you're using sqlplus, you can run this command to make your output comma-separated:

   `set colsep ","`

... then use spool and execute your query.

Comment: hey i have tried what u said: what i did is, instead of putting it dbms_output i am storing the fetched values into global temporary table. then i am turning on the spool, setting the column seperator to comma, fired a select query in that temporary table and then turning off spool. the spooled file is blank.
Where have i gone wrong?

Comment: Usually when I get a blank spool file I forgot to add a "spool off" at the end of my script, but you mentioned that you turned off spool.  Please post the script that performs the spool and the query.

Comment: DECLARE
--some Cursor block to fetch records from multiple tables                                        
BEGIN 
--modified the plsql block to format the output and insert into temporary table
 insert into notifications values(/* Fetched records are inserted into this temporary tables*/);                      
   END LOOP;
 END LOOP;
END;
/
set colsep ",";
set lines 1000000;
set pagesize 10000;
set echo off;
set feedback off;
set trimspool on;
set heading off;
spool file1.csv;
select column_names from notifications;
spool off;
Thanks for your quick responses

Comment: Not knowing the contents of the "notifications" table, I'm not sure why no output is coming out.  But it could be that there's nothing in the table.  Try removing the "set feedback off" and see if you get "no rows selected" outputted.  Just guessing, but there could be a missing commit, or your PL/SQL block isn't inserting any records.

Comment: ok let me try what u r saying and then i vil get back to u whether it is working or not.

Comment: hey i tried what u said and it is working. i tried by creating a table and inserting fetched data into it and then spooling it. now the problem is i want the column names too appear as the first line in my spooled file. after searching a lot i found out there is no way to put column names. somewhere it was written to specify pagesize as some maximum number(50000 max allowed). but my records count could exceed 1 million count. so is there any other workaround  to my problem. also i am not able to use Global temporary tables? could u help me on that? Thanks for all the help that i received.

Comment: To output the column headers yourself, you have a couple of choices.  One is to hard-code the list, and just "select 'col1, col2, ...' from dual".  The other choice, if you don't want to hard-code your columns, is to use the "user_tab_columns" view to get your list of table columns.  If you're using Oracle 11g, then use the "listagg" built-in aggregate function: "select listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by column_id) from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'".  If not 11g, then you'll have to build the list yourself using a PL/SQL block that selects on user_tab_columns.